# Pattern for get user's informations in all my services from JWT token

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, design-patterns, asp.net-core-middleware

I have an api with many controllers. One of these controllers is the authentication one. It use to get a JWT token and call others paths, from this controller or another.

My problem is, for any paths, I need to get the user id in the JWT token, and ask to the database to get informations about user, like check if the user exist or datas linked to him. So in each method, I have to call a specific method to retrieve informations.

In fact, the authentication layer is only used in order to check if the JWT Token is valid. I don't know if is it possible to add some logic in this layer. And how.

Can I implement any pattern in order to retrieve automatically user's information ?

I thought about singleton, but I'm not sure about the scope of the object. The goal is to stay in the request scope.

I thought to create an User Service, but I think it is not a good way because services are about treatment, not keep datas in these.

I thought to implement a custom middleware, but I'm not sure about the way to do it.

The objective is to implement all the user logic in the same place, and each service can call it in order to deal with it :

```
Request (with JWT Token) --> Controller --> Service --> Call the object with all user's stuff and logic and treatment
or
Request (with JWT token) --> middleware (get all user's informations) --> Controller --> Call the object created in middleware with all user's stuff
```

For information, there are my login method and the way I create the JWT token :

```
public async Task<ServiceResponse<UserLoginResponseDto>> Login(ServiceRequest<UserLoginRequestDto> request)
{
    ServiceResponse<UserLoginResponseDto> response = new ServiceResponse<UserLoginResponseDto>();
    User user = await _context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Username.ToLower().Equals(request.Data.Username.ToLower()));
    if (user == null)
    {
        response.Success = false;
        response.Message = "User not found";
    }
    else if (user.IsLocked)
    {
        response.Success = false;
        response.Message = "User locked";
    }
    else if (!user.IsActivated)
    {
        response.Success = false;
        response.Message = "User not activated";
    }
    else if (!VerifyPasswordHash(request.Data.Password, user.PasswordHash, user.PasswordSalt))
    {
        response.Success = false;
        response.Message = "Wrong password";
    }

    else
    {
        response.Data = _mapper.Map<UserLoginResponseDto>(user);
        response.Data.JWtToken = CreateToken(user);
    }

    return response;
}

private string CreateToken(User user)
{
    List<Claim> claims = new List<Claim>
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
    };

    SymmetricSecurityKey key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config.GetSection("AppSettings:Token").Value));

    SigningCredentials creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha512Signature);

    SecurityTokenDescriptor tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
    {
        Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims),
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1),
        SigningCredentials = creds
    };

    JwtSecurityTokenHandler tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
    SecurityToken token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);

    return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
}
```

Comment: what you want should be an opt-in feature which will be applied to only some specific request processing pipelines (start from controller action/page handler). So using a middleware is OK but you need to implement your own filter. I would use action filter/page filter for this scenario. Note that retrieving data for each request should be as fast as possible, so looks like you need to implement some user info cache as well (with a proper way to refresh the cache). The action filter can obtain the user info and put in the `HttpContext` which represents a shared context for the current request.

Comment: Thks for the answer. Do you have any example / tutorial / articles about this way ?

Comment: we do not need example for this kind of simple thing. All you need to know is the pipeline model of ASP.NET Core, it's like a code execution flow, on that flow you have multiple extensibility points. We can inject our code at one of such point to achieve what we want. In this case we choose action filter `IActionFilter` (or `IAsyncActionFilter`). Another earlier point is `IAuthorizationFilter` which may be better. Your code has an input of `UserId` (from the `HttpContext.Request`) from which you can load the user info and put it in `HttpContext.Items` for the next code consuming.

Comment: Actually the logics you need to do are divided into 2 concerns: the first one is ***when*** to load the user info into in-memory store. the second one is ***how*** to load that info into in-memory store as well as how to consume it from anywhere in the next code in the same pipeline. For the second concern, you can implement it your own way by designing your own mechanism to store the info in memory so that it can be easily consumed (available only in the current request processing context). The most convenient way (as I said above) is using `HttpContext.Items`.

Comment: What I commented is principle, it is much more valuable than a concrete example/demo for you to just use instantly. Providing such an answer requires more typing and I don't prefer to do that. You can search for more or wait for another one joining in here to help with a concrete answer.

Comment: Thanks for all the explaination. It's a good starting point for my search ;)